# removing item from comboBox if it matches a cetain cell in dataGridView in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of names (employees) in a comboBox that I use to add into a dataGridView. I'm trying to make it so that once the employee is in the database and displayed in the dataGrid, their name is removed from the comboBox so as not to appear available to add to the dataGrid.
The code I've written for the task looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

Public Class Main

```
Public techPhones As New PhonesDataSet.TechCompanyPhonesDataTable
Public techPhonesTableAdapter As New PhonesDataSetTableAdapters.TechCompanyPhonesTableAdapter
Public employees As New PhonesDataSet.EmployeesDataTable
Public empTableAdapter As New PhonesDataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, MyBase.Activated

    LoadForm()

End Sub

Private Sub cboEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboEmployee.SelectedIndexChanged
    lblOffice.Text = "Office: " + cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Office")
    lblPhone.Text = cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Phone")
    lblEmpID.Text = cboEmployee.SelectedItem("EmpID")
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click, DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

    Dim addEmp As New AddEmployee(cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Employee"), cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Office"), cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Phone"), _
                                  cboEmployee.SelectedItem("OfficeID"), cboEmployee.SelectedItem("EmpID"), cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Contract"), cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Returned"), _
                                  cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Loaner"))
    addEmp.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    Dim name As String = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
    Dim employee As String

    For index As Integer = 0 To cboEmployee.Items.Count - 1 Step 1
        If cboEmployee.Items(index)("Employee") = name Then
            employee = cboEmployee.Items(index)("Employee")
            cboEmployee.SelectedIndex = index
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    techPhonesTableAdapter.DeleteQuery((DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value))
    LoadForm()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadForm()
    techPhones = techPhonesTableAdapter.GetData()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = techPhones

    employees = empTableAdapter.GetData()

    cboEmployee.DataSource = employees
    cboEmployee.DisplayMember = ("Employee")
    cboEmployee.ValueMember = ("EmpID")

    lblOffice.Text = "Office: " + cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Office")
    lblPhone.Text = cboEmployee.SelectedItem("Phone")
    lblEmpID.Text = cboEmployee.SelectedItem("EmpID")
    cboEmployee.Focus()
    cboEmployee.SelectAll()
    lblRowCount.Text = "There are " + DataGridView1.RowCount.ToString + " phones accounted for."

    ' the code below is supposed to check every row in the data grid against the employee list in 
    ' cboEmployees and remove it from the list when they match
    With DataGridView1
        For indexDGV As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
            cboEmployee.Items.Remove(.Rows(indexDGV).Cells(2).Value)
        Next
    End With
    cboEmployee.Refresh()
End Sub
```

End Class

I've also tried this minor variation:

```
 With DataGridView1
            For indexDGV As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                For indexCBO As Integer = cboEmployee.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    If .Rows(indexDGV).Cells(2).Value = cboEmployee.Items(indexCBO)("Employee") Then
                        cboEmployee.Items.RemoveAt(indexCBO)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With
```

Comment: is cboEmployee an Observable collection ? rq : you can use for each.

Comment: I don't think so, although I'm really not sure. I'm new to VB and this is the first time I've heard of that, although from what I've read, an observable collection is supposed to notify you when something gets added or removed from the collection. I've not seen any kind of notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to iterate through the comboBox items.  .Remove (*string*) will work, and if the item you want to remove is not there, it ignores the command.

```
With DataGridView1
    For indexDGV As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        cboEmployee.Items.Remove(.Rows(indexDGV).Cells(2).Value)
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
With DataGridView1
    For indexDGV As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        For indexCBO As Integer = cboEmployee.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Rows(indexDGV).Cells(2).Value.Equals(cboEmployee.Items(indexCBO).Tostring()) Then
                cboEmployee.Items.RemoveAt(indexCBO)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```